# Don't refresh the input values on component change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

When I enter the input fields and switch to another component, previously entered values get refreshed.

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

How to prevent the values from getting refreshed.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/jv7mk6596v

Comment: Use stores, storage, db

Comment: @Alexis How can achieve this with stores. could you please give me a example

Comment: Use controlled components i.e. add `value` and `onChange` props to input. Store the value outside the component e.g. with redux

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu Learn about Redux. I don't have time to code this for you it's better for you to try it by yourself. https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (the `<input>`). The value of the input is only stored in the DOM, and when it's unmounted, the value is gone.

To make the value persist, we need to make it a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and keep the value of the input at an appropriate level. If you want it to persist longer than the instance of the `Home` component (and assuming you only have one `Home` component), you can keep the input value in the parent component of `Home`. E.g.:

```js
import React from "react";

const Home = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={props.value}
      onChange={event => props.onChange(event.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    home: {
      value: ""
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Home
          value={this.state.home.value}
          onChange={value => this.setState({ home: { value } })}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that this allows the value to persist even if you stop rendering the `Home` component and replace it with a new one, exactly because the state is not stored in the `Home` component itself.

Further, as an alternative to keeping the state in a component, you can also use a store (created with e.g. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)), but the principle is the same: If you want the value to persist longer than the component instance, then you must save it outside the component instance – and also, outside the elements rendered by the component instance, as you have done. However, whether you keep the state in a store or in a more long-lived component is more of an implementation detail.

### Edit

I have looked at your code example, and in your case it will probably be cleaner to use a store. However, I'll just show you an example of how you can solve it with component state. Here is your project with the necessary changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vqz30jjon

Answer (score 0):

Integrated react app with redux.

Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps. Redux makes it easy to manage the state of your application

Install related npm packages and follow this [link](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nro1m7wxnp) is my solution, using HOC and localStorage API to persist your data.